# Eclipse CDT + ICC compiler

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, icc

Is it possible to use `Intel C++` compiler (`icc`) in Eclipse (CDT) on Windows? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I could read in [this forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/170284/) *"no such integration is currently
supplied in the Windows environment for the Intel C++ compiler".*

Alternatively, there is MinGW, a free tool for developing Microsoft applications and it gives access to the functionality of the Microsoft C runtime.

See [here](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler) how to set it up with Eclipse CDT.

You can also download MinGW [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/).

Comment: Yes, thank you, but still have no idea why Intel isn't supporting ICC in Eclipse on Windows as-well.

Comment: Ok. But doesn't that answer your question James? You asked if it's possible and I answered that it isn't.

Comment: Yes, it answers. Thank you. But still amazed :-)

Comment: You're very welcome. And you're not the only one haha It's a shame they don't support it on Windows :/